# How to select duplicate rows with extra condition sql

Tags: php, sql, select, where-clause

I  want to select all duplicate records which also matching specific fix_id.

```
*------*-------------*---------*
|  id    time_stamp  | fix_id  |
*------*-------------*---------*
|  1   |   790       |  5679   |
|  2   |   1000      |  245679 |
|  3   |   1000      |  245679 |
|  4   |   12        |  245679 |
|  5   |   790       |  5679   |
*------*-------------*---------*
```

I want to get back id 2 and 3 I've tried with code below but it returns 2,3 and 4 all the records with the same fix_id

```
SELECT *
FROM odds
WHERE time_stamp IN (SELECT time_stamp
                  FROM odds 
                  GROUP BY time_stamp
                  HAVING COUNT(time_stamp) > 1) and fix_id='245679'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM odds
    a inner join (SELECT time_stamp, fix_id
                      FROM odds 
                      GROUP BY time_stamp, fix_id
                      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) b on a.fix_id = b.fix_id and a.time_stamp = b.time_stamp 
WHERE a.fix_id='245679'
```

Comment: I get error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a inner join (SELECT time_stamp, fix_id
                  FROM odds
  ' at line 3

Comment: Still the same, I google it Ifound that the inner join should come before where but I'm not sure how

Comment: Albsolutely, I have no excuse. Sorry, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `not exists`:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM odds o
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM odds o2
              WHERE o2.time_stamp = o.time_stamp AND
                    o2.fix_id = o.fix_id AND
                    o2.id <> o.id
             )
WHERE a.fix_id = 245679;
```

Using aggregation in a subquery is a bad habit, when `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS` does the trick.  Aggregation needs to process all the data, whereas `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS` can stop at the first matching record.